# Don't manage to open a vim buffer in a python script

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to write a python script which creates some new files i use frequently.
All of this stuff works. I go in the directory in which i want to create my files (.tex) and then execute my sript.py. My new files are here.

After that, I would like to automatically open a vim window with my main file on which i can start writing. That works too with this line :

```
os.system('vim '+nom_fichier+'.tex')
```

Now my problem :

I would like to open two other files as buffers in my vim session at the end of my script too.
I have tried :

```
vim.command('e other_file.tex')
```

But that doesn't work.
I should precise some other things :

1. In vim, the following command works and opens a new buffer :

   :python3 vim.command('e newfile.txt')
2. The vim version i'm using is 8.0.
3. With the vim module imported, i get an error telling me that this module **doesn't exist**

I think the problem comes from this last point but i don't know what to do.

Comment: You cannot import module `vim` outside of vim — it's a module built-in into vim. You can try to use [client/server functionality](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#clientserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phd mentioned, you can't import the `vim` module because it's built into Vim.  However, if your goal is simply open some files, you can pass multiple arguments on the command line, and that will work just fine.  You can then switch between them using `:bnext` (or `:bn`) or by using whatever method you normally use to switch buffers.

If you need to do more advanced things, you could try the client / server functionality, or you could write a Vim function in your `.vimrc` (for example, `TexStart`) and then add run it on start like this:

```
os.system('vim +"call TexStart()" ' + nom_fichier + '.tex')
```

Comment: thanks, of course you're right, i'll try to simply complete my os.system command. I feel a little bit stupid for havn't tried it first ^^'. Thanks for your other suggestions too.